# Get the id of an iframe by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onclick

I have a div `id = "tabs2"` which contains 4 iframe, I want when I click on an iframe, I recovered its id, I did that but it did not work:

```
    $("document").ready(function() {
       elm= document.getElementById("tabs2");
       frames=elm.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
       for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){
            frames[i].click(function(){
               alert(this.id);
            })
       }
    });
```

Comment: Do not use quotes around document.

Comment: Of course iframes are from same domain than parent document, right?!

Comment: $('iframe').click( function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});  This will work

Comment: when I click on the border, I recovered the id. 

My iframe contains a youtube video. how do I recover retrieve the id when I click the middle of the iframe (eg the play button)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('iframe').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: $('iframe').click( function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });    Works

Comment: when I click on the border, I recovered the id. 

My iframe contains a youtube video. how do I recover retrieve the id when I click the middle of the iframe (eg the play button)

Answer (score 0):

using jquery.

if you need an id whenever the iframe inside the element tabs2 is clicked , then

try this

```
 $('#tabs2').find('iframe').click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
 });
```

else

```
$('iframe').click(function(){
   alert(this.id);
 })
```

this tracks the click event of all the iframe that is currently present in the document

Comment: when I click on the border, I recovered the id. 

My iframe contains a youtube video. how do I recover retrieve the id when I click the middle of the iframe (eg the play button)